# convert the uploaded file (xls) to xml

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, file-upload, apache-poi

I have been making an app that can convert the uploaded file to xml file. The uploaded file is xls file.
I have made the xls converter to xml with apache-poi.
I have made the upload and download functions too.
When the xls file is being uploaded, it should be converted to xml by the controller and is saved in database (Mysql), but it fails.
The app returns an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream
```

And this is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class FileController {

@Autowired
private FileDAO documentDao;

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String showDocument(Map<String, Object> map) {
    try {
        map.put("document", new File());
        map.put("documentList", documentDao.list());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "documents";
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("document") File document,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Name:" + document.getName());
    System.out.println("Desc:" + document.getDescription());
    System.out.println("File:" + file.getName());
    System.out.println("ContentType:" + file.getContentType());

    /*
     * start to convert xls to xml
     * */
    try {
        InputStream input = (InputStream) file;
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
        HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.newDocument();
        doc.setXmlStandalone(true);

        Element spectraexchange = doc.createElementNS("http://www.lstelcom.com/Schema/SPECTRAexchange", "SPECTRAEXCHANGE");
        spectraexchange.setAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        spectraexchange.setAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        spectraexchange.setAttribute("version", "2.4.28");
        doc.appendChild(spectraexchange);

        for(int i=1; i<=2; i++){

            HSSFRow row = spreadsheet.getRow(i);

            Element application = doc.createElement("APPLICATION");
            spectraexchange.appendChild(application);

            Element svid = doc.createElement("SV_SV_ID");
            application.appendChild(svid);
            svid.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("12"));

            Element ssid = doc.createElement("SS_SS_ID");
            application.appendChild(ssid);
            ssid.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("140"));

            Element address = doc.createElement("ADDRESS");//men-generate <ADDRESS>
            application.appendChild(address);//men-generate </ADDRESS>
            address.setAttribute("AD_TYPE", "L");

            Element adspplus = doc.createElement("AD_SPPLUS_TYPE");//men-generate <AD_SPPLUS_TYPE>
            address.appendChild(adspplus);//men-generate </AD_SPPLUS_TYPE>
            adspplus.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("L"));//<AD_SPPLUS_TYPE>L<AD_SPPLUS_TYPE>

            try {
                Element adcompany = doc.createElement("AD_COMPANY");
                address.appendChild(adcompany);
                adcompany.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(row.getCell((short) 33).getStringCellValue()));
                if(row.getCell((short) 33).getStringCellValue()==null){
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }

            try {
                Element adstreet = doc.createElement("AD_STREET");
                address.appendChild(adstreet);
                adstreet.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(row.getCell((short) 35).getStringCellValue()));
                if(row.getCell((short) 35).getStringCellValue()==null){
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }


            Element adcountry = doc.createElement("AD_COUNTRY");
            address.appendChild(adcountry);
            adcountry.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("INS"));

            try {
                Element adcity = doc.createElement("AD_CITY");
                address.appendChild(adcity);
                adcity.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(row.getCell((short) 36).getStringCellValue()));
                if(row.getCell((short) 36).getStringCellValue()==null) {
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }

            Element station = doc.createElement("STATION");
            application.appendChild(station);

            Element transmitter = doc.createElement("TRANSMITTER");
            station.appendChild(transmitter);

            try {
                Element eqpname = doc.createElement("EQP_EQUIP_NAME");
                transmitter.appendChild(eqpname);
                eqpname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(row.getCell((short) 2).getStringCellValue()));
                if(row.getCell((short) 2).getStringCellValue()==null){
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }


            Element eqptype = doc.createElement("EQP_TYPE_IS_APPROVED");
            transmitter.appendChild(eqptype);
            eqptype.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("1"));

            try {
                Element eqpmodel = doc.createElement("EQP_EQUIP_MODEL");
                transmitter.appendChild(eqpmodel);
                eqpmodel.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(row.getCell((short) 4).getStringCellValue()));
                if(row.getCell((short) 4).getStringCellValue()==null){
                    continue;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }

            try {
                Element eqpprod = doc.createElement("EQP_EQUIP_PROD");
                transmitter.appendChild(eqpprod);
                eqpprod.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(row.getCell((short) 6).getStringCellValue()));
                if(row.getCell((short) 6).getStringCellValue()==null){
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }


        }

        TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tfactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http:/xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");

        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        //StreamResult result = new StreamResult("E://XlsToXml/standard_query02.xml");
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        /*
         * end of convertion
         * */

        //----------------------------------//
        Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(((MultipartFile) doc).getInputStream());

        document.setFilename(((MultipartFile) doc).getOriginalFilename());
        document.setContent(blob);
        document.setContentType(((MultipartFile) doc).getContentType());

        documentDao.save(document);

    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
         System.out.println("ParserConfigurationException " + e.getMessage());
    }  catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
         System.out.println("TransformerConfigurationException "+ e.getMessage());
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
         System.out.println("TransformerException " + e.getMessage());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:/index.html";
}

@RequestMapping("/download/{documentId}")
public String download(@PathVariable("documentId") Integer documentId,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    File doc = documentDao.get(documentId);

    try {
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\""
                + doc.getFilename() + "\"");
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType(doc.getContentType());
        IOUtils.copy(doc.getContent().getBinaryStream(), out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@RequestMapping("/remove/{documentId}")
public String remove(@PathVariable("documentId") Integer documentId) {

    documentDao.remove(documentId);

    return "redirect:/index.html";
}

}
```

Maybe there's something I have to do with the controller.
Any ideas, solution, or suggestion is greatly welcomed and appreciated.

Best Regards,

Yunus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the line giving that error.

```
InputStream input = (InputStream) file;
```

You cannot cast a `MultipartFile` object `file` directly to `InputStream`. You need to use the `getInputStream()` method of `MultipartFile`, like this:-

```
InputStream input = file.getInputStream();
```

Comment: it works. Now, the controller can get the file and be able to convert the file to xml. But, the app returns a new exception : 
'java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile'

and the file cannot be saved to database.
any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Glad to be able to help you!:)